# Kali Update Issue - 403 Forbidden/Reposotory is not signed

Tags: kali-linux

Recently I've been facing issues while updating my Kali box. I thought something's wrong with my `source.list` file or one of the files in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` so, I downloaded the Kali Docker image (kalilinux/kali-linux-docker:latest) and tried updating it but I face the same error with it too. I wonder if something's wrong with my network. How can I confirm it? Here's the error:

> Kali Box

```
root@testb0x:/# apt update
Get:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,182 B]
Get:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [142 kB]
Err:3 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.107 80]
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.107 80]
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

> Docker Container

```
root@c43b09d0b7be:/# apt update
Err:1 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.107 80]
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.107 80]
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

146.113.61.107 does **not** seem to be the IP address of `ftp.harukasan.org`!

```
$ nslookup 146.112.61.107
107.61.112.146.in-addr.arpa     name = hit-malware.opendns.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
112.146.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = auth2.opendns.com.
112.146.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = auth1.opendns.com.
auth1.opendns.com       internet address = 208.69.39.2
auth2.opendns.com       internet address = 146.112.60.53
auth1.opendns.com       has AAAA address 2620:119:30::53
auth2.opendns.com       has AAAA address 2a04:e4c0:53::53

$ dig +short ftp.harukasan.org @8.8.8.8
14.49.100.116
211.219.253.179
14.49.99.238
14.49.100.37
```

If you're using OpenDNS as your DNS service provider, it will redirect you to `hit-malware.opendns.com` if you try to access a known malware-infected site.

So, it looks like the Kali Linux mirror `ftp.harukasan.org` may have recently had a malware infection.

Or perhaps the problem is your router? If it has been infected by malware, it might be attempting to redirect your (and your `apt update` command's) web access to a bad site instead of where you actually wanted to go, and then your (or your internet provider's) DNS server is filtering for malware sites and responds with the IP address of `hit-malware.opendns.com` instead.

On the other hand, `ftp.harukasan.org` is not mentioned in the [official list of Kali Linux mirror sites](https://docs.kali.org/community/kali-linux-mirrors) so the fact that `apt` is trying to access it is suspicious.

If you are a home or small-business user, I recommend that you reboot your router: disconnect its power for 10..30 seconds, then plug it back in and wait for it to reboot. If this seems to fix things, it might have been non-persistent router malware: check the router vendor's support site, and apply the latest available router firmware upgrade if there is one, to hopefully prevent re-infection. If you are in a larger organization, contact your network administrators.